# Looking for an easy explanation of exec in PHP

Tags: php, exec, php4

I am having trouble understanding the `exec` function in PHP. Can someone please explain it to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec — Executes command cmd in the system's command interpreter and returns the last line of output. Optional arguments allow the command output and return value to be captured.

string exec(cmd[, array_name][, $return_value]);
string cmd: Command to be executed

Answer (score 0):

[`exec`](http://php.net) will call a program on the pc which runs your script and will return the last line of the output. e.g.

```
$result = exec('echo bla');
echo $result; // outputs 'bla'
```

(usually you don't want to use it, and some shared hosting servers do not allow it's usage due to security concerns)

Answer (score 0):

i prefer shell_exec http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php it returns all output

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/exec

(There seems little point in providing any other answer without a more specific question)